# Update primary key column of other rows when a row is deleted

Tags: c#, mysql, database

In my database, there is a table which essentially contains questions with their options and answers. The first field is ~questionid~ and is the primary key, as expected (I've disabled AUTOINCREMENT for now). It's possible that my client wants to delete some questions. This leaves me with two options:

1. All subsequent questions move up so that there is no empty row. This option implies that those questions will have their question id changed
2. Leave it as it is so there will be empty rows. If a there's a new entry, it should fill the first empty row.

How do I go about implementing any of them? I prefer the second, actually, but if anyone has a different opinion, it's welcome.
I'm using a MySQL database and C#.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a database so you don't have to worry about these issues.

There is no concept of "empty" row in a SQL table (well, one could say if all the columns are NULL then the row is empty, but that is not relevant here).  Rows in a SQL table are not inherently ordered.

The rows themselves are stored on pages, which may or may not have extra space for more rows.  This may be what you are thinking of when you think of an empty row.

When a row is deleted, the data is not rearranged.  There is just some additional space on the page in case a new row is added later.  If you add in a new row with a primary key between two existing rows, and the page is full, then the database "splits" the page into two.  The two other pages have extra space.

The important point, though, is not how this works.  One reason you are using a relational database for your application is so you can add and delete rows without having to worry about their actual physical storage.

If you have a database that has lots of transactions -- deletions and insertions -- then you may want to periodically rearrange the data so it fits better on the pages.  Such optimizations though are usually necessary only when there is a high volume of such transactions.

One thing, though.  Your application should not depend on the primary keys being sequential, so it can handle deletes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you have implemented.  I would have done it in this way,

```
  questions
     question_id - pk
     question

  answers
     answer_id - pk
     answers

  question_answer
      question_id
      answer_id
```

This will give more advantage.  many questions will have same answer.  if a question can be deleted then delete them along with their answers from question_answer table